# Finding the intersection of a circle and a line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

The text says:

> On a single set of coordinate axes, sketch the line $x+16 = 7y$ and
>   circle $x^2+y^2-4x+2y=20$ and find their points of intersection. Hint: eliminate x algebraically and solve the resulting
>   quadratic equation in y.

I take the following steps:
Put the circle in standard form by completing the square:
$(x-2)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 25$
Rewrite the line equation in terms of x:
$x=7y-16$
Substitute x into the equation of the circle:
$(7y-16-2)+y+1=5$

Doing so gives me a value of $11/4$ for y. The text gives an answer of $(-2,2)$and $(5,3)$.

I've gone wrong somewhere but can't pinpoint exactly where.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to have performed $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{a^2}+\sqrt{b^2}=a+b$, which is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The putting in standard form is not useful here. Just plug in $7y-16$ everywhere you see $x$. So we get $(7y-16)^2+y^2-4(7y-16)+2y=20$. Expand and simplify.

Comment: Redo the substitution. It should be $(7y-16-2)^2 + (y+1)^2=25$. Eliminate the parentheses and solve for y.

Comment: But aren't $\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (y+1)^2} = \sqrt{25}$ and $(x-2) + (y+1) = 5$ equivalent? i.e. I'm taking the square root of both sides of the circle equation before substituting x.

Comment: @Nick Would you say that $$5 = \sqrt{25} = \sqrt{4^2 + 3^2} = \sqrt{4^2} + \sqrt{3^2} = 4 + 3 = 7?$$
This very common error is known as the [freshman's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman's_dream).

Comment: I'm not sure whether I should be more, or less, embarrassed that there's a Wikipedia page for my error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have changed the equation of the circle to a line equation, which is wrong.

$(7y-16-2)^2+(y+1)^2=5^2$

Comment: But aren't $\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + (y+1)^2} = \sqrt{25}$ and $(x-2) + (y+1) = 5$ equivalent? i.e. I'm taking the square root of both sides of the circle equation before substituting x

Comment: No. They are not. As a counter example $\sqrt{3^2+ 4^2}= \sqrt{25}=5 \neq 3+4$

Comment: Remember that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 +  2ab + b^2$